# Function to read line in Word on every keypress - Word Addin

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I'm trying to write an addin for Microsoft Word that can read the entire line of text in a Word document and compare it to a dictionary on every keypress (it doesn't matter what the keypress is). Essentially, every time the user types anything, I want to be able to read the line of text and save it to a variable. I still need the keypress to register in Word and type like usual. How do I make a function that runs every single time a key is pressed?

I have never coded an addin for Word in Javascript before, so it's possible I have missed something obvious, so feel free to treat me as a complete beginner.

I started with this starter file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=visualstudio

I added this code which didn't do anything:

```
var doc = Office.context.document;
doc.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged, function () {
    insertEmersonQuoteAtSelection;
    console.log('Ran new function.')
});
```

I also added the addEventListener line and the line below it in this section of code, which also didn't do anything:

```
(function () {
    Office.onReady(function () {
        // Office is ready.
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // The document is ready.
            // Use this to check whether the API is supported in the Word client.
            if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', '1.1')) {
                // Do something that is only available via the new APIs.

                addEventListener('keydown', insertEmersonQuoteAtSelection);
                $(document).keypress(insertEmersonQuoteAtSelection);

                $('#emerson').click(insertEmersonQuoteAtSelection);
                $('#checkhov').click(insertChekhovQuoteAtTheBeginning);
                $('#proverb').click(insertChineseProverbAtTheEnd);
                $('#supportedVersion').html('This code is using Word 2016 or later.');
            }
            else {
                // Just letting you know that this code will not work with your version of Word.
                $('#supportedVersion').html('This code requires Word 2016 or later.');
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 39) {
                    insertEmersonQuoteAtSelection;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I also added the second $(document).ready(function () { line to see if a specific key (e.g. 39) would work, and it didn't.

I just wanted to see if I could run a test function (e.g. insertEmersonQuoteAtSelection) that I know works on a keypress, and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

You should use addEventListener like the following:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', insertEmersonQuoteAtSelection);
```

I have tried this, it does work.
And I don't know where you put the first code snippet, so I don't make a try, maybe it's also some use error, you can have a check or provide more information.

And the recommended way to generate an add-in is using the Yeoman generator. You can have a try about this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator

Comment: you code works only in the taskpane, not in the word document